# iOS MDM creation Trust Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mdm, apple-profile-manager

I am creating an in house MDM solution and have managed to create everything I need in terms of the MDM server, SCEP server etc in order to gather information about our devices.

However, I am having an issue pushing the Enterprise Apps that we create. I can push the apps to the device (and they install without issue) but I am still presented with the 'Do you Trust this developer' prompt.

I was under the impression that Enterprise Apps should be trusted by default when deployed by MDM. I have tested this using Apples Profile Manager and indeed the application is installing without issue and does not require the user to trust the developer.

I am obviously missing something obvious but have been chasing my tail trying to find out what it is!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

David

Answer (score 1):

OK. Turns out the issue was actually not much better that a typo!

Having uploaded the app to my server, I had a manual creation of the manifest for installation. The app identifier in the manifest did not mach the actual app!

So... weirdly the app was pushed via MDM, the manifest was downloaded (and appeared under the control of MDM briefly) then iOS realised mad things were afoot so booted the app out to the normal enterprise installation process (untrusted developer dialogue etc).

Fixing the manifest bundle identifier to match the app fixes the issue.

That's many hours I'll never get back!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are missing a CA certificate/root certificate that you used to sign your app. Due to this iOS might have been unable to trust the app since it was not able to confirm the validity of the signing cert.